# Updating Box2d to 2.2.1 in Cocos2d V1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I've been using Cocos2d V1 and Box2d that comes bundled with it. 
I'm trying to update to the newer version of Box2d which is Box2d V2.2.1.

I've updated the Gles-Render.h and Gles-Render.mm to the latest versions I did some changes that got rid of all the errors except one.

```
debugDraw = new b2Draw();
world->SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);
debugDraw->SetFlags(b2Draw::e_shapeBit);
```

I get error:

```
ERROR: allocating an object of abstract type 'b2Draw'
```

I've been trying to fix this for two days now but to no prevail.

Any body have a solution to this?

any Pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to add the b2Draw class to your project. In addition I don't think you should be using b2Draw but GLESDebugDraw. At least the projects I work with use a GLES-Render file where a GLESDebugDraw class is defined which derives from b2Draw (which I believe was named b2DebugDraw in Box2D v2.1).

```
class GLESDebugDraw : public b2Draw
```

If in doubt, use someone else's GLES-Render files. You can get ones that are working with Box2D v2.2 from Kobold2D:

[GLES-Render.h](https://github.com/kobold2d/Kobold2D/blob/master/Kobold2D/_Physics-Box2D-Template_/Projectfiles/GLES-Render.h)
[GLES-Render.mm](https://github.com/kobold2d/Kobold2D/blob/master/Kobold2D/_Physics-Box2D-Template_/Projectfiles/GLES-Render.mm)